# React: Loading image based on dynamic path results in error

Tags: reactjs, image, require

I'm trying to load images based on a dynamic path in react but the result is the following error `Cannot find module <path>`

The following code is working

```
const TestImage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="image-wrapper">
      <img src={require('./../../../assets/images/guy-holding-pencil.jpg')} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I broke down the dynamic part to the use of a variable which is not working

```
const TestImage = () => {
  const image = './../../../assets/images/guy-holding-pencil.jpg';

  return (
    <div className="image-wrapper">
      <img src={require(`${image}`)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The path is correct. The only difference is the variable. The result:

```
Error: Cannot find module './../../../assets/images/guy-holding-pencil.jpg'.
```

Edit: My project is created with `create-react-app`

Comment: I also tried to putting image in different locations to see what actually happening is. I think only matter is the path variable. If you can show me the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach ?

```
import IMAGE1 from './../../../assets/images/guy-holding-pencil.jpg';
```

Then

```
const TestImage = () => {


return (
<div className="image-wrapper">
  <img src={IMAGE1} />
</div>
);
};
```

Comment: If the amount of images should be under something like 10 and I should know all the paths in advance, that approach could work but this is not the case. I'm looking for a dynamic way. The paths can come from a database or .cvs file and the amount of paths is unknown.

Comment: No.. You can loop through it and render. images.map(image=>return <img src={image}).

Comment: As you said it will coming from database as array of paths ..say here images array. Then you can loop and return jsx.

Answer (score 0):

In some case you can use command require, because exists deffer between relative and absolute path.
I try go to npmj org and find dropzone plugin for solving this problem